# Error when converting to EWSId on Exchange 2013 works ok on Exchange 2010

Tags: powershell, exchangewebservices

Hello when I run the following piece of code.

$service.ImpersonatedUserId = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ImpersonatedUserId([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ConnectingIdType]::SmtpAddress, $MailboxName)

function ConvertId{
    param (
            $OwaId = "$( throw 'OWAId is a mandatory Parameter' )"
          )
    process{
        $aiItem = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.AlternateId
        $aiItem.Mailbox = $MailboxName
        $aiItem.UniqueId = $OwaId
        $aiItem.Format = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.IdFormat]::OwaId
        $convertedId = $service.ConvertId($aiItem, [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.IdFormat]::EwsId)
        return $convertedId.UniqueId
    }
}

## Get Folder id from EMS and bind to the Folder in EWS

get-mailboxfolderstatistics $MailboxName | ForEach-Object {

```
$folderid = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FolderId((Convertid $_.FolderId))     
$ewsFolder = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Folder]::Bind($service,$folderid)  
$ewsFolder
```

}

I receive the following error. Should the method be different for Exchange 2013.

ForEach-Object : Exception calling "ConvertId" with "2" argument(s): "Data is corrupt."
At D:\Scripts\SAVE SCRIPTS\Get-FoldeIDsr.ps1:89 char:44
+ get-mailboxfolderstatistics $MailboxName | ForEach-Object {
+                                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [ForEach-Object], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ServiceResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ForEachObjectCommand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to URLEncode the FolderId you get from EMS as it may have illegal characters eg

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web        
$urlEncodedId = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode($_.FolderId.ToString())
$folderid= new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FolderId((Convertid $urlEncodedId))  
$ewsFolder = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Folder]::Bind($service,$folderid)
```